# symfony2 autoload.php executes on my computer, but not on remote

Tags: symfony, autoload

this is my `app/autoload.php`

```
use Doctrine\Common\Annotations\AnnotationRegistry;

$loader = require __DIR__.'/../vendor/autoload.php';

// intl
if (!function_exists('intl_get_error_code')) {
    require_once __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale        /Resources/stubs/functions.php';

    $loader->add('', __DIR__.'/../vendor/symfony/symfony/src/Symfony/Component/Locale    /Resources/stubs');
    $loader->add('Stof', __DIR__.'/../vendor/bundles');
    $loader->add('Gedmo', __DIR__.'/../vendor/gedmo-doctrine-extensions/lib');
    $loader->add('Zend\\Search' , __DIR__.'/../src/EWZ/zends');
    $loader->add('EWZ', __DIR__.'/../src/EWZ');
}
```

the problem is, it executes the condition on my computer (loads the classes), but not on the other computers that download it through git. when i put `die` in the condition, it stops for me, but not for other computers.
can anyone tell me what does the condition do? as i've been failing miserably for last two hours in resolwing the problem. thx

Comment: The condition will be entered if the [intl](http://php.net/manual/en/book.intl.php) extension doesn't exist for the current version of PHP. It sounds as though your remote servers do have it installed, but you don't locally.

Comment: Exactly what @RobMasters said, but I don't see, where this could lead to a problem. Whats the concrete problem you want to solve?

Comment: thanks guys for your comments, they were very helpful. zend search and ewz wasn't supposed to be in the condition brackets. could any of you post your comment as an answer, so i can accept it? thanx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"The condition will be entered if the intl extension doesn't exist for the current version of PHP. It sounds as though your remote servers do have it installed, but you don't locally."  RobMasters